# tf keras, custom loss function that require multiple network outputs as inputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I've recently decided to try tf2.0, especially the high level keras API. I am not too familiar with keras either, have mainly been using tensorflow before. However, I cannot find a good way of using custom loss functions. Take a simple example, let's suppose we have a multi-input, multi-output model defined as follow:

```
# define model
... your network definition
...

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=[output_1, output_2, output_3])
```

Let's suppose I have two custom loss functions: `my_loss_1` requires `output_1, output_2` and `targets_1` in order to compute the loss. Similarly `my_loss_2` requires `output_2, output_3` and `targets_2`. My questions are:

1. Is there a way to do this by sticking to the high level API?
2. How can I pass training data to the model? If I have constructed a dataset as

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((input_ds_1, input_ds_2), (target_ds_1, target_ds_2))
```

and pass it to `model.fit`, then the model will assume to compute `loss_1` using `output_1` and `target_ds_1`, which is not what I intended.

3. I'm not even clear how the data correspondence rule is when using tf.data with keras, its not explained anywhere. My guess is that a training dataset should be a tuple of `(inputs, targets)`. If your network takes multiple inputs, then the inputs is another tuple of `(input_1, input_2, ...)`, same with targets. Is this correct?
4. Is there a way to reuse the data passed to the model? Suppose now both `my_loss_1` and `my_loss_2` require `target_1`, do I have to change my `train_ds` to contain duplicates?

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((input_ds_1, input_ds_2), (target_ds_1, (target_ds_1, target_ds_2)))
```

Comment: Maybe you can use it as a layer and use dummy loss?

Comment: Like this https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo3/blob/master/yolo.py

Comment: You could try concatenating the targets before fitting the model. When you want to define the custom loss, you could access the concatenated targets and outputs of the model, by using model_output_1, model_output_2 = y_pred[:, :split_point], y_pred[:, split_point:].

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful @Manos

Comment: Add custom loss as a layer and use dummy loss on output seems strange, but I'm starting to like it.@NatthaphonHongcharoen